# Selecting second foreign key when inserting row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert-into

```
INSERT INTO `images` (s_id, u_id, name, filename, filesize, uploaded)
SELECT s_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM servers
WHERE name = ?
```

I'm currently using this SQL statement when a user uploads an image to my site. The `s_id` field is a foreign key to the `servers` table, and the field `u_id` is a foreign key to the `users` table. I want to select the user id (u_id) from the users table by their username (always unique) and use it in this insert statement.

I've already done the part that selects the server id (`s_id`) but that was pretty much fluke and messing around. I'm not quite sure how to adapt this query to have two select statements?

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE userID int
SELECT u_id FROM users into userID
WHERE useranem = ?
```

Then use the useriD variable in your INSERT afterwards. I'm a SQL Server user, not MySQL, but from what I read I think I got the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `images` (s_id, u_id, name, filename, filesize, uploaded)
SELECT (select s_id from servers where name=?') as s_id, 
(select user_id from users where username=?) as user_id, 
?, ?, ?, ?;
```

Comment: From what i can tell, the other ???'s also come out of SERVERS, so the OP would need those values as well and you'd end up with many sub-queries.

Comment: Where do you store name, filename, filesize, uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something like this so that you get two unique index scans and that's the end of it; as long as the tables are uniquely indexed on both the unique key and the value you wish to be returned.

```
insert into 'images' (s_id, u_id, name, filename, filesize, uploaded)
select ( select s_id
           from servers
          where name = ? )
     , ( select u_id
            from users
           where username = ? )
     , 'name'
     , 'filename'
     , 'filesize'
     , 'uploaded'
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one mentioned

```
INSERT INTO `images` (s_id, u_id, name, filename, filesize, uploaded)
SELECT s_id, u_id, ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM servers JOIN users 
WHERE name = ? AND username = ?
```

It is an unconditional join, but it nevertheless should yield only one row, with the given server and user.

Comment: Works a treat, the other methods did seem a little complicated. Thanks! :)